# How to create a drop down list on the Mozilla web browser using XUL and Javascript?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla

I want to create a drop down list on the Mozilla browser which is Mozilla extension! I know how to create a button but the drop down menu doesn't seem to work! Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Do you want to create the drop down menu using pure XUL or do you want to create it with Javascript? How does the code look like that doesn't work`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/menulist